# Register PhoneListener in android

Tags: android

How do I register PhoneStateListener with the TelephonyManager via `listen()` in android programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Its clearly mentioned in API of TelephonyManager class ,

> Registers a listener object to receive notification of changes in
>   specified telephony states. To register a listener, pass a
>   PhoneStateListener and specify at least one telephony state of
>   interest in the events argument. At registration, and when a specified
>   telephony state changes, the telephony manager invokes the appropriate
>   callback method on the listener object and passes the current
>   (udpated) values. To unregister a listener, pass the listener object
>   and set the events argument to LISTEN_NONE (0).

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen(android.telephony.PhoneStateListener, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29)